# How to send an email from PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to send an email from my PHP script but it doesn't work. This is the error I get:

```
Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and 
"smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

So I've tried to change the port and smtp port by using `iniset()` function, may i don't know is it possible or not.

Comment: This has nothing to do with mysql. You may be able to edit the php.ini file directly using a text editor.

Comment: Yes it is possible.You have compulsory set SMTP and smtp port in php file using php ini_set() function

Answer (score 2):

If you are on linux you must have a mailserver installed i.e. postfix to do so, issue this command `apt-get install postfix` and after this the server is started and you can use the php `mail()` function to send emails!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to setup a mail server on your localhost. Or, you could connect to an external mail server. Hell, even Gmail allows you to connect via SMTP (cool for testing email scripts etc).

Answer (score 0):

> So I've tried to change the port and smtp port by using iniset() function, may i don't know is it possible or not.

It is. See [the manual for mail configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php). Both those entries are marked as PHP_INI_ALL

You can prove this by using `iniset` and then trying your mail call again. The error message will either go away or change (e.g. to complain that it can't connect to whatever server you've said to use instead of localhost:25).